# Stockfish misses mate in 11 with 10 pieces

Tags: endgame, stockfish, rook-endgame

I fed [@HaukeReddmann's "hack"](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/42589/33019) to [this scenario](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/42581/33019)

```
[FEN "8/p7/rp6/rp6/pP6/R7/8/K6k w - - 0 1"]
```

to [Lichess Stockfish 14](https://lichess.org/analysis/standard/8/p7/rp6/rp6/pP6/R7/8/K6k_w_-_-_0_1), white to move. Up to Depth 77 (after which I gave up waiting), it declares draw, and suggests `Ka2` as best move. Yet, the moment I play `Kb1`, it immediately realizes mate in 11 for white.

Shouldn't 10 pieces be easy? Surely, eventually, it realizes M11 - but why not already with 38 (77/2) moves? And why doesn't Stockfish consider `Kb1` for itself (since it instantly realizes M11 when I play it)?

**Clarifying**, [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/37345/33019) explains my second question, but not quite the first and last. I get that ultimately it's heuristics, but is there something to specifically explain how it fails to find mate with just 10 pieces, *and* that me making the right move makes it see mate? Yes, longer wait (or better hardware, it runs on cloud) would help, so it's a question on efficiency (which moves it chooses to discard).

Comment: Stockfish isn't designed to solve endgame puzzles, but play realistic games well.

Comment: This https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37333/why-does-it-take-stockfish-depth-35-to-find-mate-in-7?rq=1 should answer your question (observed the same in the position, initially was as flabbergasted as you).

Comment: @Allure Hmm sort of, though I'd prefer an answer to this more focused question.

Comment: What about this, does it answer your question? https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29417/why-are-world-class-engines-playing-like-this/39722#39722

Comment: @Allure Well, an idea with Stack Exchange is direct answers to questions as-asked. If I have to dig much to find relevance, it's not a duplicate. An answer that merely cites an excerpt from another answer would count (likely along brief commentary).

Answer (score 0):

My instance of Stockfish 16 saw M11 after about 7 seconds, so I think you just didn't wait long enough, although Stockfish 16 is stronger than 14 so that could also be why.

Comment: Indeed that makes sense. Curious, at what search depth did it see M11?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Stockfish are you using? I am using Stockfish 15.1, with Chessis Pro GUI on Android 13, Snapdragon 8 Gen 1, and it found the mate in few seconds with depth around 70.

Edit: sorry, I missed the part where you say the version of the engine.